# Laravel websockets + pusher-js - UI side connected but doesn't get data

Tags: laravel, websocket, echo, pusher-js

**problem :**
socket connects successfully and its status is 101. but doesn't get any data on event call.

**note :** everything works perfectly on local server.

```
Alt-Svc: h3-24=":8443"; ma=86400, h3-23=":8443"; ma=86400
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
CF-RAY: 5555c1ef7d12d600-MXP
Connection: upgrade
Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 06:22:51 GMT
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: kdvICu1oe8EKBkC5xoqRFMkJruA=
Server: cloudflare
Upgrade: websocket
X-Powered-By: Ratchet/0.4.1
```

broadcasting.php pusher connection :

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 8443,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
```

Echo configuration :

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: true,

    disableStats: true,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 8443,
    wssPort: 8443,
});
```

**note :** i'm using cloudflare.

Comment: Are you using a laravel-websocket package or direct request to pusher api ?

Comment: laravel-websockets